# Azure AD service principal add optional claim value with powershell

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to create GCP workload identity federation with Azure AD service principal but when I am trying to create the initial sts token with GCP I get bad request. I am suspecting that the problem is that my audience currently on jwt token is "https://management.azure.com" where it should be the audience that is set in the GCP WiF configuration. Currently I am getting the Azure AD accesstoken with:

```
$AzContext = Get-AzContext
$accesstoken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate(
    $AzContext.'Account',
    $AzContext.'Environment',
    $AzContext.'Tenant'.'Id',
    $null,
    [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never,
    $null,
    'https://management.azure.com/'
).AccessToken
```

But is it possible to extend this command to populate my optional claim? Currently my manifest looks like this:

```
"optionalClaims": {
    "idToken": [
        {
            "additionalProperties": [],
            "essential": false,
            "name": "onprem_sid",
            "source": null
        }
    ],
    "accessToken": [],
    "saml2Token": []
},
```

Comment: Please refer to this link for reference : - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I managed to get the proper audience in place without optional claims is that I used the application id with the tenant name:

$AzContext = Get-AzContext
$accesstoken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate(
$AzContext.'Account',
$AzContext.'Environment',
$AzContext.'Tenant'.'Id',
$null,
[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never,
$null,
'https://cfbf35b2-6346-48dc-9ac2-b77e77f90933.mytenant.onmicrosoft.com'
).AccessToken

I also did put that as my application id URL and the audience on GCP configuration and managed to get proper token from GCP.

Answer (score 0):

•   To get optional claims in the Access token, you will have to define them in your app manifest since access tokens are always generated using the manifest of the resource, not the client. To configure optional claims,

1. Go to the Azure portal.
2. Search for and select Azure Active Directory.
3. Under Manage, select App registrations.
4. Select the application you want to configure optional claims for in the list
5. Then under manage, select manifest option which opens an editor and edit the access token option in it as given below as a sample for reference to get the optional claims configured in the access token. Once finished, save it and the claims will be included in the token for your application: -

The following application manifest entry adds the auth_time, ipaddr, and upn optional claims to ID, access, and SAML tokens.

```
 ‘ "optionalClaims": {
    "idToken": [
    {
        "name": "auth_time",
        "essential": false
    }
],
"accessToken": [
    {
        "name": "ipaddr",
        "essential": false
    }
],
"saml2Token": [
    {
        "name": "upn",
        "essential": false
    },
    {
        "name": "extension_ab603c56068041afb2f6832e2a17e237_skypeId",
        "source": "user",
        "essential": false
    }
]
} ‘
```

[image: AADB2C Optional claim]

So, once you save the manifest with the above said changes and request an access token as usual according to the command stated by you, these mentioned optional claims will be included in the JWT access token.

Please refer this below link for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#configuring-optional-claims